# How do you combine multiple IF functions with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, submenu

I am looking to see if there is a more efficient way for the following code: thank you:)

```
$( ".menu" ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});

$( ".menu2" ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu2" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});

$( ".menu3" ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu2" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index) {
  $( ".menu"+index ).click(function() {
    $( ".submenu"+index ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: that is really cool Neeraj, thank you :) can you tell me why the last menu will not close or toggle when it's main menu is clicked? http://jsbin.com/iwUNAwO/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do it some thing like this using [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]] and use the class name to get the common number for `submenu` class[1](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$( "[class^=menu]" ).click(function() {
   num = this.className.replace('menu', '')
  $( ".submenu" + num ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
     // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".menu" ).click(function() {
   $( ".submenu" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
   // Animation complete.
   });
});

 $( ".menu2,.menu3" ).click(function() {
   $( ".submenu2" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
   // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks to those who commented i have found two ways to make a more logical jQuery. thank you all for your help, couldn't have done it without you!!!

for example, I tried Neeraj's example but had a problem with the last menu/submenu not closing with JSBin. With a little trial and error, It seemed that by adding another number (in this case, 4) this now allowed the menu/submenu #3 to open/close perfectly. not sure why but it worked for me!

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index) {
$( ".menu"+index ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu"+index ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
}
```

thanks again!

I also noticed that JSBin is a great tool (it shows any errors with red font that is easily noticed).

JSfiddle is also great when you want to "tidy up" your code, what a real time saver! My website is really coming along and I couldn't be happier. thanks to all who have made comments and examples.